# Start Internet Explorer, wait until the user closes it, then exit the script

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have a script that opened IE with no toolbar and to navigate to a url (below)

```
Dim IE, URL
URL = "website.com"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  IE.Navigate URL
  IE.Visible = 1
  IE.ToolBar = 0
  IE.Left = 0
```

I need to have the window appear like this for reasons,
I cant use kiosk mode.

What I need to do is:

- run the script (LaunchIE_noToolbar.vbs)
- open IE, hide toolbar, go to url
- wait in the background while the user does stuff which might be 10-15 minutes later
- recognize it's closed and exit the script

It seems simple enough, but I can't work it out, the waiting part is driving me nuts.

If you can do this in PowerShell that would be great too, I don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in front of a computer right now, but as I recall...

You can start a process aka start-process I think. Grab the process ID which is returned. Then wait for the process to complete, might be wait-process?  Do a "help process" at the PowerShell prompt for commands and syntax.

Comment: If you start IE using `Start-Process`, you won't be able to control it via COM Automation (calling `.Navigate()`, setting `.ToolBar`, ...), which the OP requires. _Generally_, however, you can use `$newProc = Start-Process -PassThru ...` (note the need to use `-PassThru`) to obtain a `[System.Diagnostic.Process]` instance representing the process just started, and wait for its termination via `Wait-Process $newProc.Id`.

Comment: Also, in the future, I recommend either waiting till you're back at a computer before answering, or coming back later to solidify your answer. SO is [different from traditional forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/248777).

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant PowerShell solution, but this seems to work:

```
$url = "website.com"
$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate($url)
$ie.Visible = 1
$ie.ToolBar = 0
$ie.Left = 0

# Wait for IE to exit.
while ($null -ne $ie.ReadyState) { # .ReadyState is only $null once the IE instance exits
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}
```